# VSTO Outlook: Issue when a custom button is "pin to ribbon" on simplified ribbon menu view and the button visibility is set to false

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, ribbonx

I have a custom button placed in the ribbon menu. I have observed that when ribbon menu is in simplified view and the visibility of my custom button is set to false (not show it), then my button continues showing instead of hiding. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `IRibbonUI.Invalidate` or `IRibbonUI.InvalidateControl` methods to update the ribbon controls when you changed the control's state. The add-in can also then force an immediate update of the UI by calling the `Refresh` method.